# form editing with codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i'm trying to edit my form field with codeigniter. The submitted values first shown the view and then the informations are edited. but when i submit the form the following error occurs

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: views/tupdate.php

Line Number: 46

in line 46 I have

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $info[0]->id  ?>">
```

My controller :

```
 function update($id = 0)
 {
   $data['info'] = $this->trainingUpdate_model->getdata_by_id($id);

   $this->load->view('tupdate', $data);
 }


function super()
{
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $data['title']=$this->input->post('title');
    $data['training_description']=$this->input->post('training_description');

    if ($this->trainingUpdate_model->update($id, $data)==TRUE)
    {
      $this->load->view('traing_update_success');
    }
    else
    {
      $this->load->view('S_unsuccess');
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
 function getdata_by_id($id = 0)
 {
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $sql = $this->db->get('training');
    return $sql->result();
 }


 function update($id,$data)
 {
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->update('training', $data);

   if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
   {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
 }
```

And View:

```
 <form action="trainingUpdate/super" method="post">

   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $info[0]->id  ?>">
   Title Name:<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($info[0]->title) ?>">
   Title Name: <textarea type="text" name="overview" value=""><?php echo $info[0]->training_description; ?></textarea>

   <input type="Submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

I'm getting why the information in not updating and why am getting that error.

please help. thanks

For some reason the submitted values are not getting into trainingUpdate/super() method, from where the submitted data is passed to the model. the from is going back to the same view page and giving the error. can anyone tell me why it is happening?? thanks again.

Comment: Assuming the view you show us is `tupdate.php` and you're loading it in the `update()` method, you need to dump out what your query result is. In your controller, you can dump `data` before you load the view and you should see your query results. My guess is that you won't. You can work back from there.

Comment: My guess is that $info is not an array. Dump $info on your tupdate page to see what it holds.

Comment: the dump result is the array(0) { }

Comment: $info is empty, so it's not getting assigned properly in your controller. You'll need to make sure that $this->trainingUpdate_model->getdata_by_id($id); is passing back what you're expecting.

Comment: now info is showing result. but still nothing is updating. i also changed the array name to field name but nothing is working

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting only one row to update record then use only row() method to fetch only record

**Model**

```
function getdata_by_id($id = 0)
 {
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $sql = $this->db->get('training');
    //return $sql->result();
    return $sql->row();
 }
```

**view**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $info->id  ?>">
```